# How to echo foreach() data variable if conditioned by a foreached data variable?

Tags: php

i have a table tbl_tmpdtr and tbl_employee and using this query to fetch the needed data:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_tmpdtr.id, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid, 
    date(tbl_tmpdtr.in_out) as in_out,
    time(tbl_tmpdtr.in_out) as dtr_time, 
    tbl_tmpdtr.status,
    tbl_employee.emp_id,
    tbl_employee.emp_fname,
    tbl_employee.emp_mname,
    tbl_employee.emp_lname
FROM 
    tbl_tmpdtr 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_employee 
ON 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid = tbl_employee.emp_id 
WHERE 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid='(some id)'
GROUP BY 
    tbl_tmpdtr.userid

sample output query:
id | userid |  inp_out   | dtr_time | status
1  | 1002   | 2015-05-01 | 09:00:00 | In
2  | 1002   | 2015-05-01 | 18:30:00 | Out
```

> I foreached this data in my view where I have there two separate input
>   types labeled as "In" and "Out", my problem is HOw to put the dtr_time
>   09:00:00 in the Input type labeled as "In" IF the status='In', and on
>   the other hand, the next dtr_time 18:30:00 in the input type labeled
>   as "OUT" if the status='Out'?

I tried but even at dtr_time with the status as OUT goes to the input type labeled as In.

Here is what I've tried.

```
  <?php if(!empty($dtr)){foreach ($dtr as $dtrs): ?>

      <h4>  
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Full name: </label>
          <?php echo ucfirst($dtrs->emp_lname).", ".ucfirst($dtrs->emp_fname).", ".ucfirst($dtrs->emp_mname)."."; echo "</br>";?>              
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> EMP_ID: </label>
          <?php echo $dtrs->emp_id;?></br></br>
      </h4>
                  <div>              
                        <table class="display table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th bgcolor="2ECC71"><center><font color="white">Date(s)</font></center></th>
                            <th bgcolor="2ECC71"><center><font color="white">In</font></center></th>
                            <th bgcolor="2ECC71"><center><font color="white">Out</font></center></th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>  
                          <tr>
                          <center>
                            <td align="center"><input type="date" value="<?php echo $dtrs->in_out;?>"></td>
                            <?php if($dtrs->status == 'In'){?>
                            <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $dtrs->dtr_time;} else if($dtrs->status == 'Out'){?>"></td>  
                            <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $dtrs->dtr_time; } else { echo "do nothing";}?>"></td>
                          </tr>
                          </center>
                        </table>
                  </div>
  <?php endforeach; }?>
```

Comment: Please add the php code also.

Comment: And what you have tried. Show your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this ways it'll work as desired

```
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="date" value="<?php echo $dtrs['inp_out']; ?>"></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($dtrs['status']) && $dtrs['status'] === 'In') ? $dtrs['dtr_time'] : '----' ?>"></td>  
        <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($dtrs['status']) && $dtrs['status'] === 'Out') ? $dtrs['dtr_time'] : '----' ?>"></td>
    </tr>
```

You have typo within your code `in_out` must be `inp_out`

Comment: can't do it in array, i'm using codeigniter. So i revised it like this:   <td align="center"><input type="date" value="<?php echo $dtrs->in_out; ?>"></td>
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($dtrs->status) && $dtrs->status === 'In') ? $dtrs->dtr_time : '----' ?>"></td>  
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($dtrs->status) && $dtrs->status === 'Out') ? $dtrs->dtr_time : '----' ?>"></td>

Comment: Sorry didn't get you but you can access variables in CI as I have shown and its working for me

Comment: wait @uchiha, why is it in the input type OUT you are giving a value of '-----' instead of the dtr_time that has an id='2'?

Comment: What I have done over here is its checking the values with status if `status == In` then it'll place the value within `<td>` of `In` and vice versa

Comment: Whats the problem you were facing what is your expected output just update your question with expected output

Answer (score 1):

If you sort by userid, tbl_tmpdtr.in_out you can iterate over your array and check against the userid of the next index.

```
<?php
$count = count($result);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    if (($i+1) >= $count) {
        echo "User: " + $result[$i]["userid"];
        echo "Status:" +$result[$i]["status"];
        echo "Date: " + $result[$i]["inp_out"] + " - " + $result[$i]["dtr_time"];
    }

    if (
    $result[$i]["userid"] == $result[($i+1)]["userid"] &&
    $result[$i]["status"] == "In" && $result[($i+1)]["status"] == "Out" ) {
        echo "User: " + $result[$i]["userid"];
        echo "In: " + $result[$i]["inp_out"] + " - " + $result[$i]["dtr_time"];
        echo "Out: " + $result[$i+1]["inp_out"] + " - " + $result[$i+1]["dtr_time"];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        echo "User: " + $result[$i]["userid"];
        echo $result[$i]["status"]": " + $result[$i+1]["inp_out"] + " - " + $result[$i+1]["dtr_time"];
    }
}
```

But there shouldn't be more #Out+1 'Ins' than 'Outs'